# how to see data going to output while debugging?

Tags: sas

I wonder if I can see data going to an output file during each iteration while debugging. Using DEBUG option allows me to see what is going on during each iteration but I can’t see which data got written to an output file during each iteration.

I think it is important to know as some programs include more complex options like looping, retaining, output, @ or @@ etc.

Thanks,
Yulia

Comment: Can't you open the file and see what got written to it? If you are on linux you could have a tail running in a seperate window? Also, you could copy the put statements and change them to putlog, so you can see in the log what got written.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything in the data step debugger to specifically show the output files.  I don't believe it's specifically compatible with ODS.  You can use `ODS TRACE` to see what things are being created, but I don't think that's what you're asking.  Other than Stig's suggestion above I don't believe there's any automatic way.  Data step debugger is for viewing the PDV primarily, not the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you amend your data step code to include an extra variable indicating which part of the data step each bit of output came from. You don't have to include this in the output dataset, but next to each `put` statement you can include a corresponding `putlog` statement.